# Change the size of the legend when using scale_fill_gradientn() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new here, I hope I'm not doing anything wrong for my first post!
I'm using R again (it's been ages, almost 15 years when I first used it).
It's impressive how powerful it is.
Anyway, I'm trying to do heat maps using ggplot2 and I'm nearly there.
There's just the text of the legend of my scale that I need to modify (namely increase the font size and put bold characters).
Here's the piece of code I use:

```
yellowgreen <- c("yellow", "dark green") 
pal <- colorRampPalette(yellowgreen)(100)
library(ggplot2)

data <- read.table("file_directory", sep=";", header = T)

v <- ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(A, B) , y = Pourcentage, fill = B))
v + geom_tile() + geom_text(aes(label = round(B,1)), color = "black", size = 4, fontface=2) + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = pal, name = expression("Legend Title")) + 
labs(y = "Title for Y", x ="Title for X") +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size=24, color="black"), axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold",size=24, color="black"), axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=24, color="black"), axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=24, color="black"))
```

Could you please help me to increase the font size of the legend and put it bold?
Thanks a lot
Cheers

Comment: Does `legend.text = element_text(face = "bold", size=24)` in `theme` not do what you want?

Comment: It does! With legend.title also.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comment. Thanks anyway, I did not have the right keyword 